# Avoiding infinite loop in ItemsControl having radiobutton value set by Converters

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, itemscontrol, converters

I have this code in WPF 
Every new form gets added by clicking on "Add New" to the Itemscontrol.

Event is a CSLA call.

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="Add New"
                    csla:InvokeMethod.MethodName="AddNew"
                    csla:InvokeMethod.TriggerEvent="Click" />
    </Menu></ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <FrameworkElement x:Key="ReqProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid>
                    <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ReqProxyElement}" />
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.DataContext>
                            <formviewmodels:ReqViewModel Model="{Binding Source={StaticResource ReqProxyElement}, Path=DataContext}"  />
                        </Grid.DataContext>
                        <formviews:ReqView />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Now inside the form ReqView, I have converter call for radio button.

```
<Label Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0" Content="required"  />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" >
        <!--<RadioButton Content="Yes" GroupName="Required" IsChecked="{Binding Model.Required, Converter={StaticResource NullableBooleanToFalseConverter}}"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="No" GroupName="Required" IsChecked="{Binding Model.Required, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBoolean}}"></RadioButton>-->
        <RadioButton Content="Yes" GroupName="GRequired" ></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="No" GroupName="GRequired" ></RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
```

In this scenario when I click on add New , the ItemsControl as is the nature of the beast tries to bind back to the Form and goes into an infinite loop in the converter call.
The converter code is given below.

```
public class ReverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return (!((bool)value));
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return (!((bool)value));
        }
        return value;
    }
}

public class NullableBooleanToFalseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Can any one come up with a solution where the convereter don't kick the code into infinite loop. 
What happens is when a Add New is clicked, if there is already a form in the Itemscontrol, it tries to bind back to the form again before creating a new empty form.
The binding back sets the radio button true say if true is selected but then setting it to trus starts a tennis match between the two converters one converts it the other converts it back and the model says No way the value is true and so on it goes until application hits stackoverflow...

Interesting situation I have hit into with WPF and MVVM pattern.I am looking for a solution without breaking the MVVM paradigm. If converters can be done away with that will work too.
The backend calls are CSLA reistered properties.

Thanks
Dhiren

Answer (score 0):

You can bind only the `Yes` radio. Since it's `IsChecked` property is bound to your bool, the bool would turn to false when you check the other radio. You don't even need the `ReverseConverter` here.

**UPDATE:**
Only bind the `Yes` radio to your field. `RadioButton` are mutually exclusive when they are in the same group (which they are). When you select one, you change the other. If you select the `No` radio, yes would be unchecked, and so `Required` would be `false`.

As for the initial values, if you set `No` to false, it would be selected. And since `Yes` is bound to `Required`, it'll save your value. Do something like this:

```
<RadioButton Content="Yes" GroupName="GRequired" IsChecked="{Binding Required}"/>
<RadioButton Content="No" GroupName="GRequired" IsChecked="False"/>
```

**UPDATE II:**
The binding mechanism in WPF ties two values together, so when one changes the other does too, and it can work both ways. `RadioButton.IsCheck` is just a bool property, so when it's value change it changes the value it's bound to (in this case `Required`). When you check `No`, you also uncheck `Yes`, it's `IsChecked` property changes. and that changes `Required`.
 For more on Data binding see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx.

So, you see, you don't need the `ReverseConverter`, because you don't need to bind `No` to anything. As a matter of fact, you don't even need `NullBooleanConverter`, since WPF already knows how to convert `bool?` to `bool`.

Regards,
Yoni

Comment: How would the No button ever get selected if no converter is bound to that radio button ?Say the value for Yes does not get selected, how would the No get selected in that situation ?

Comment: I did the following and now ..           <RadioButton Content="Yes" GroupName="GRequired" IsChecked="{Binding Model.Required, Converter={StaticResource NullableBooleanToFalseConverter}}"></RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Content="No" GroupName="GRequired" IsChecked="{Binding Model.Required}"></RadioButton>
and now when I add a form No is selected by default but the moment

Comment: I selected yes or no or save the form, both radio button selection disappear and I can never select them again try as much , the converter reverts it to unselected for Yes or No. Also adding the Adding New does not crash application but does not seem to add  anew Form either. Appreciate your quick responses that you gave for suggestions. Thanks Dhiren

Comment: Thanks for the update.I was again debugging but I am puzzled why a true gets switched to false for the Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the update.I was again debugging but I am puzzled with what I see. The NullableBooleanToFalseConverter gets called with true and immediate after a ConvertBack is called on that converter which returns a false. Who changes that to false..ReverseBoolean get called with false => selected and immediately after a Convert back is called on NullBooleantoFalseConverter. ..What kicks in the tennis  match ? I was thinking the two converters but if the value remained true then this would not have happened driving it to infinite loop

Comment: Yoni I tried what you said. In retriving the data in the form it will work as long as Yes is selected. If I have No selected and saved and this is what I have  <RadioButton Content="Yes" GroupName="GRequired" IsChecked="{Binding Required}"/>
<RadioButton Content="No" GroupName="GRequired" IsChecked="False"/>. Retriving if No selected and saved comes up with both buttons deselected so I think reverseconverter would be needed.adding reverseconverter and then clicking 'Add New' goes into stackoverflow

Comment: No, if you change No's `IsChecked` to True, it should work. As long as you set `Required`'s value **after** `InitializeComponents()` the binding would get notified, and the value would change. What you wrote looks fine, just change No's `IsChecked` to True.

Comment: I had to end up creating a database field for Yes and No for every radio button. it just did not work.The binding is also so sensitive in MVVM that it breaks every now and then so that I used to end up with a Yes and No being selected at the same time.